# Chat system using Mysqli, PHP and AJAX is inserting blank message into Database

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, mysqli

I've hit a brick wall in my chat system project and I have tried all day to find a solution. So here I am.

In the file insert.php I am trying to use $_REQUEST to get the value of the textarea from chat.php.

When I type something in and click send, a blank message is sent to the database.

After playing around with it, sometimes the webpage displays a "1" in the div element im trying to display the message in.

Any help would be very much appreciated thank you.

**chat.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>{ Chat App }</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "styles/style.css" media = "all" />
    <script src="insert.js"></script>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rokkitt' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
    <form name = "form1">
        <textarea name = "message"></textarea>
        <br>
        <a href = "#" onclick = "submit()">Send</a>
        <br>
        <div id = "msg"></div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

**insert.js**

```
function submit(){
    if(form1.message.value == ''){
        document.writeln('Enter some text fool.');
    }
    var msg = form1.message.value;
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); // main object

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) { // data is ready
            document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; // txtHint div now displays the data received by the request
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'insert.php', true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**insert.php**

```
<?php
    include("connection/connection.php");
    global $con;

    $msg = isset($_REQUEST['msg']);

    $insert = "INSERT INTO msg (message) VALUES ('$msg')";
    $run_insert = mysqli_query($con, $insert);

    $get_msg = "SELECT * FROM msg ORDER by id DESC";
    $run_msg = mysqli_query($con, $get_msg);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_msg)){
        echo $row['message'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: xmlhttp.open('GET', 'insert.php', true); try changing to   xmlhttp.open('GET', 'insert.php?message='+msg, true);

Comment: you forgot to add the message in your query string

Comment: xmlhttp.open('GET', 'insert.php?message='+msg, true); - that didn't work. I tried changing ?message to ?msg. That displayed a 1.

Comment: as Rodrigo said..you forgot to send your message along with the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is when you check for the null value, the function continues and submits the form if it is null or not.

**insert.js**

```
function submit(){
    if(form1.message.value == ''){
        document.writeln('Enter some text fool.');
        // stop the submit action
        return;
    }
    var msg = form1.message.value;
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); // main object

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) { // data is ready
            document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; // txtHint div now displays the data received by the request
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'insert.php', true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

The next problem is in the form handler, you are saving a boolean value `isset($_REQUEST['msg'])`. Try this

**insert.php**

```
...
$msg = (isset($_REQUEST['msg']) && !empty($_REQUEST['msg']) ? $_REQUEST['msg'] : false;
if($msg){
  // save data to database 
  ...
}
```

**or**

```
...
if((isset($_REQUEST['msg']) && !empty($_REQUEST['msg'])){
  // message was submitted and it is not an empty string
  $msg = $_REQUEST['msg']; 
  // save data to database 
  ...
}else{
  // do nothing
}
```

Comment: You fixed my problem. Thank you, you're a beast. Could you please elaborate on why this worked in any more ways? The second point you raised solved it.

Comment: You were using `$msg = isset($_REQUEST['msg']);` which gives $msg a boolean true/false value. When php outputs a boolean true = 1 and false = 0, so as long as `$_REQUEST['msg']` is set with any value your code was recording it as `1`

Answer (score 0):

`xmlhttp.open('GET', 'insert.php', true);` try changing to `xmlhttp.open('GET', 'insert.php?msg='+msg, true);`

Hope it helps !

Comment: al right what does your ajax returns if you use echo $_REQUEST['msg'];die; in your php file ?

Comment: It echos what I typed in the textbox, but does not store in the database. Hmmm

Comment: echo your query same way and try running directly in phpmyadmin .. you might find a problem there.

Comment: Keeps displaying a 1 and inserting a 1 into the database.

Comment: And when you echo query it shows message in insert query ? check your column type in database , what is it text ? varchar ?

Answer (score 0):

better to add "return" on error when you check if message is empty

```
if(form1.message.value == ''){
    document.writeln('Enter some text fool.');
}
```

so it could be

```
if(form1.message.value == ''){
    document.writeln('Enter some text fool.');
    return;
}
```

in submit() function
so the rest of function will not execute and empty message won't be sent.
and assign to variable message not the validation ))

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['msg']) && !empty($_REQUEST['msg'])){
    $msg = $_REQUEST['msg']; //addiotionally this need escape
    $insert = "INSERT INTO msg (message) VALUES ('$msg')";
    $run_insert = mysqli_query($con, $insert);
}
```